# Sony camera API | DSC-HX60 | connecting/controlling multiple cameras with one android device

Tags: android, camera, sony

i need to develop an android app wich controls about 4 cams. with wifi direct i can control only one camera via the sony api as the cam acts as access point.
so i connected the hx60 to the wireless router where the android device is connected. but i only can ping the camera when im connecting to the playmemories camera apps application (from the application list in camera menu). im not able to call anything via the api. is it even possible with a router in between?
if not, how to connect to multiple cameras else?

thanks alot!

stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible through the Camera API to connect multiple cameras to a single device.

Comment: ok. thanks for your answer. so i think i have to use cameras with an android os.